# Разница между 'разузнать' и 'узнать'

Tags: значения

В Мастере и Маргарите (в девятнадцатой главе): `Она сделала все, чтобы разузнать что-нибудь о нем, и, конечно, не разузнала ровно ничего.`

В чем разница между этими двумя словами? Спасибо!

И еще один вопрос: в моем первым предложении, можно ли сказать `я случайно натолкнулся на следующую фразу` (I ran across the following phrase), если я хочу говорить просто фигурально, а не физически? Надеюсь, что оба моих вопросов понятные.

Answer (score 6):

*Разузнать* - это произвести какие-либо активные действия с целью узнать.
*Узнать* - это просто узнать. Например, случайно.

О приставках *раз-*, *рас-* и *разо-* на [ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-):

> при добавлении к глаголам образует глаголы со значением усиления интенсивности

И да, предложение *я случайно натолкнулся на следующую фразу* вполне употребимо в фигуральном смысле.

Comment: Спасибо большое, Dmitry! :)

Comment: @Конрад [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://russian.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Конрад Please follow the link above and read the article.

Comment: I feel the impulse to say 'thank you' here as well, but I wouldn't want to give anyone here the impression that I was socializing :P

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что 'раз-' придает действию некий успешный ход совершения. И возможно, в фразе из книги, автор хотел отгородиться от распространенного использования слова "узнать" как действия идентификации кого-то в встретившемся человеке. Например, "Я узнал в прохожем своего знакомого."